# Counting duplicates List (Java)

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates

I want to count the duplicate in an ArrayList in Java, how can I do it?

In particular, I'd like to create an app that tells me how many prime factors are in a given number, and I save all of them in an ArrayList of integers.

Then, the ArrayList looks like this (for example, number 100) [2, 2, 5, 5]

I would like to count somehow how many 2 there are, how many 5...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the frequency function of a collection :

`int occurrences = Collections.frequency(yourList, whatToCount) ;`

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Map for this use case. Something like below:

//Put all values in Map

```
   for (Integer temp : list) {
            Integer count = map.get(temp);
            map.put(temp, (count == null) ? 1 : count + 1);
        }
```

//Iterare map and view duplicates

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Found Duplicate for " + entry.getKey() + "  "
            + entry.getValue()+"  times.");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a frequency count by using groupingBy and counting like this

```
List<Integer> factors = ...
Map<Integer, Long> factorCount = factors.stream()
                            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i), Collectors.counting());
```

It would be simple to count the number of each factor as you generate them instead of producing a List.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println(factorise(2L*2*2*5*5*49*11));
}

static Map<Long, Integer> factorise(long value) {
   Map<Long, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
   for (int i = 2; i * i <= value; i++) {
       while (value % i == 0) {
           map.merge((long) i, 1, (p, n) -> p == null ? n : p + n);
           value /= i;
       }
   }
   if (value > 1)
       map.put(value, 1);
   return map;
```

}

prints

{2=3, 5=2, 7=2, 11=1}

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to do this manually, you can use a `for` loop and a `Map`:

```
//Get your list in the appropriate way
ArrayList list = getList();

//Make a HashMap
HashMap<int,int> map = new HashMap<>();

for (int i : list) {
    if (map.containsKey(i)) {
        map.put(i, map.get(i)+1);
    } else {
        map.put(i, 1);
    }
}
```

You will then have a map relating `int` keys to the number of occurrences of that `int` in the `List`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and Wrapper patterns to enclosed a set of methods to compute prime number as well as other stuff.

This is a bit different solution from @Peter Lawrey because it is using a Unit Testing on jUnit framework and [Stream Lambda](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html). This solution maybe useful to test and check dynamically if the methods are computing correctly.

```
public class ComputePrime {

    public boolean isPrime(int n) {
        int i;
        for (i = 2; i <= n/2 ; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void throwExceptionIfIsNotPrime(int n){
        if(!isPrime(n))
            throw new IllegalStateException("It is not prime");
    }

    public List<Integer> generatePrime(int n){
        List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            if(isPrime(i))
                primes.add(i);
            else continue;
        }

        if(primes.isEmpty())
            return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
        else return primes;
    }

    public List<Integer> dupPrimes(List<Integer> primes){
        primes.forEach( i-> throwExceptionIfIsNotPrime(i) );

        List<Integer> dupPrimes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Integer prime : primes) {

            dupPrimes.add(prime);
            dupPrimes.add(prime);

        }
        return dupPrimes;
    }

    public List<Integer> dupRandonPrimes(List<Integer> primes){
        primes.forEach( i-> throwExceptionIfIsNotPrime(i) );

        List<Integer> dupPrimes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Integer prime : primes) {
            dupPrimes.addAll(generatePrimeDup(prime));
        }
        return dupPrimes;
    }

    private Collection<? extends Integer> generatePrimeDup(final Integer prime) {
        final int n = ((int) (Math.random()*10) % 10) +1;
        List<Integer> dupPrimes = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            dupPrimes.add(prime);
        }

        return dupPrimes;
    }

    public Map<Integer,Long> countPrimes(List<Integer> primes){
        Map<Integer,Long> primeOnMap = new HashMap<>();

        primes.forEach( i-> throwExceptionIfIsNotPrime(i) );

        for (Integer prime : primes) {
            long count = primes
                            .stream()
                            .filter(i -> i == prime)
                            .count();

            primeOnMap.put(prime, count);
        }
        return primeOnMap;
}}
```

---

```
public class ArrayListSolutionTest {


    @Test
    public void testCheckGeneratePrimeOnList() throws Exception {
        List<Integer> primes     = new ComputePrime().generatePrime(100);
        List<Integer> dupPrimes  = new ComputePrime().dupPrimes(primes);

        Assert.assertTrue( !primes.isEmpty() );
        Assert.assertEquals((primes.size() * 2), dupPrimes.size());
    }

    @Test
    public void testCountPrimeOnList() throws Exception {
        List<Integer> primes     = new ComputePrime().generatePrime(100);
        List<Integer> dupPrimes  = new ComputePrime().dupPrimes(primes);

        Map<Integer, Long> countPrimes = new ComputePrime().countPrimes(dupPrimes);

        Assert.assertEquals( countPrimes.size(), dupPrimes.size()/2 );

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Long> entry : countPrimes.entrySet()) {
            Assert.assertEquals( entry.getValue(), new Long(2) );
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testCountPrimeOnList_Aleatory() throws Exception {
        List<Integer> primes          = new ComputePrime().generatePrime(100);
        List<Integer> aleatoryPrimes  = new ComputePrime().dupRandonPrimes(primes);

        Map<Integer, Long> countPrimes = new ComputePrime().countPrimes(aleatoryPrimes);

       Assert.assertNotNull( countPrimes );
    }}
```